# Team Foundation Version Control - Windows Authentication - Command Line

Tags: tfs, tfvc, azure-repos

Interacting with a Repo in TFVC is working fine through Visual Studio.
I'm trying to pull the history on the command line and write it to a CSV.

```
tf folderdiff $/<serverFolder> F:\<localFolder> /recursive /noprompt /collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

I get a 404, I've tried looking at the LoginType switch, but can't find anything to pass windows integrated authentication.

How can I passthrough Windows Authentication on the command line?

Comment: Windows auth is automatically passed. 404 in this case probably indicates the collection URI isn't correct.

Comment: Thanks - turns out I had an extra "/" on the end of DefaultCollection.

Answer (score 0):

`tf` can be quite picky when it comes to the collection URI, you guess that the format could be normalized quite well, but `tf` takes it exactly as you've passed it in.

As you mentioned even a trailing `/` at the end can throw it off.